# secrets in visual studio and git

Tags: git

So, i'm confused in how to use secrets in viusal studio using asp.net core.

So i realised you have 'manage user secrets' in visual studio.

When i look at github, for example connectionstring in app.config it's like

```
<your connectionstring>
// or
username=username
password=password
```

I assume you use a local file with secrets and a copy default you commit to git.
However i don't know how to use them.

i used this links to try out:

[User secrets](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3576292/how-to-work-with-user-secrets-in-asp-net-core.html)

[docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

The same for docker compose, so in this link I assume you create an env file with your secrets and use this? But what do you commit them? I assume you don't have 2 files with both the same names?

Comment: You *don't* put secrets in source control. Ever. You use an external secret storage mechanism.

Comment: Yes i recognized that why i askked the question youi have some kind of default empty environmental file which you commit and another which you don't commit and use. The questiuon is how to use it -> local secrets to use and empty default to commit

Comment: Add files that shouldn't be source controlled to your .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

Raw git doesn't have support for secrets, but many platforms built on top of it do. For example: [GitHub Encrypted Secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) and [GitLab CI Secrets](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/).